# xpath to find elements with redirections within same domain

Tags: selenium, xpath

I am trying to write xPath which identifies all the links on a page within a domain.

Eg: I want an xPath on http://www.yahoo.com page which highlights all the hyperlinks on the page that redirects within the same yahoo domain.

I am using

```
//a[starts-with(@href,'https://yahoo.com/us')]
```

but is not highlighting all the links.
What corrections should I make?

Comment: Can you please share full code which you have written?

Comment: Can you list the full url of some of the links that are not "highlighted", but that you thought would be highlighted?

Comment: Haven't written any selenium code yet. I'm just trying to identify all the hyperlinks on a page (which doesn't redirect to an external domain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working fine for me

```
        driver.get("http://www.yahoo.com/");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        List<WebElement> list=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@href or @src]"));

        for(WebElement e : list){
               String link = e.getAttribute("href");
               if(null==link)
                   link=e.getAttribute("src");

           if(link.contains("https://s.yimg.com/"))
           System.out.println(e.getTagName() + "=" + link);
       }
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: I want only the links within the same domain, not all the links present on the page :(

Comment: ok, I have updated my code. I think there is no URL with https://yahoo.com/us . so I used https://s.yimg.com/. Have a try .. it is working for me

Comment: or replace that 2nd last line of my code with if(link.contains("yahoo.com/?p=us"))

Comment: Thanks Shubaham.
I was trying to do something else, but the code you've given kinda serves my purpose. Will modify it per my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this  `//a[contains(@href,'yahoo.com')]`

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to check what differences in DOM are there between what's not highlighted vs what's highlighted. 
As far as I understand, you are looking for all the links with 'us' domain, try the following as per your requirement:

```
//a[contains(@href,'yahoo.com/us')] 
or //a[contains(@href,'/us')]
```

Comment: I was trying the above solution too, before i post on StackOverflow.
But this just returns 'True'. Neither a count nor highlights any element.
Anyway i can get this xPath to highlight the elements?

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it worked. Thanks!